# Concourse CI: Use Metadata (Build number, URL etc) in on_success/on_failure

Tags: concourse

How is it possible to use [Metadata](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/email-resource) in `on_success`/`on_failure`? For example, to send emails via https://github.com/pivotal-cf/email-resource?

I haven't found a way, as I can't change content of files where email resources reside (subject/body), as the metadata is not available to tasks.

And yep, that might be a duplicate for [Concourse CI and Build number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771347/concourse-ci-and-build-number)

But still my question IMHO is a valid use case for notifications.

Answer (score 2):

The metadata you are referring to, I assume, is the [environment variables](https://concourse-ci.org/implementing-resource-types.html#resource-metadata) provided to resources, not tasks.

This can be used with the [slack resource](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/slack-notification-resource) to provide information about what build failed.

For example:

```
on_failure:
    put: slack-alert
    params:
      text: |
        The `science` pipeline has failed. Please resolve any issues and ensure the pipeline lock was released. Check it out at:
        $ATC_EXTERNAL_URL/teams/$BUILD_TEAM_NAME/pipelines/$BUILD_PIPELINE_NAME/jobs/$BUILD_JOB_NAME/builds/$BUILD_NAME
```

The email resource, you're referencing has an [open PR](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/email-resource/pull/12) to support these environment variables. I'd discuss your need for that feature there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've subscribed to that PR on Github.

Comment: Is this really the best way to get the URL for a build on Concourse CI? They don't expose a _single_ env var for this, such as `BUILD_URL` with Jenkins?

Comment: @AutonomousApps, correct, they deliberately hide the information to stop people from doing things they consider bad practice, like using concourse job identifiers for versioning.

Comment: what about when using other resources? Does the resource have to support this specifically?